# How to read files from a directory and find files with a specific extension -scala

Tags: scala

I need to read files from a directory and find files with a certain extension, so first add them to a runner that progresses with reading the files

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
to see what and  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). 
if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

The `java.io.File` class can read files in a directory which can then be converted to a list and filtered by the file extension. The example below would return a list of zip files in the current directory.

`new java.io.File(".").list.filter(file => file.endsWith(".zip"))`

`res26: Array[String] = Array(foo.zip, bar.zip)`

Comment: How about `filter(_.endsWith(".zip"))` to make it a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [better files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files) library. Here is [ammonite](http://ammonite.io/) snippet:

```scala
import $ivy.`com.github.pathikrit::better-files:3.8.0`
import better.files._ 
val mit:Iterator[T] = File("/home/scalway/some/path")
  .children.filter(_.extension.contains("zip"))
```